# Can't create multiple objects in class

Tags: c++

When I try to create more than one object, I get an error saying no matching function for call. I don't understand, usually I can create as many objects as I want without a hitch but the moment I add a parameterized constructor in the equation, suddenly I'm not allowed to create more than one object. Why is it so?

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Point
{
private:
    int x, y;
public:
    Point(int x1, int y1)
    {
        x = x1;
        y = y1;
    }
    int getx()
    {
        return x;
    }

    int gety()
    {
        return y;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Point c2, c3;
    Point c = Point(10, 20);
    cout << c.getx() << " " << c2.gety() << " " << c3.getx() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You explicitly declared a constructor `Point(int x1, int y1)`, so the compiler-generated default constructor is disabled.

You can add one to the class declaration like this:

```cpp
Point() : x(0), y(0) {}
```

Or, in C++11 or later, you can add a default constructor like this (be careful, the `int` members won't be initialized by this):

```cpp
Point() = default;
```

Comment: "*be careful, the `int` members won't be initialized by this*" - they will be if you declare them with default values, eg: `private: int x = 0; int y = 0;` That is another feature added in C++11 to compliment the `= default` feature.  An alternative would be to simply merge the 2 constructors together: `Point(int x1 = 0, int y1 = 0) : x(x1), y(y1) { }` That will allow a single constructor to act as both a converting constructor and a default constructor.